# Hadoop HDFS rsync dry-run equivalent

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, rsync

I'm looking for a way to compare two HDFS clusters path. We have 2 hadoop clusters (one for production and one for disaster recovery) and I'm investigating for missing/different files on certain paths.
Something like

```
rsync -rvn --size-only --delete path1/ path2/
```

would be awesome. The distcp tool can be used to push files from one cluster to another, but is there an Hadoop tool to do just a comparison? I know that I could do this via script, checking recursively the file listings (name + size) but I would like to understand if there is something already set up.

Comment: This looks interesting - [HSync](https://github.com/alexholmes/hsync)

Comment: Thanks @philantrovert but this repo seems quite old (2012) and no code is available inside

Comment: Oops. I can't open this link at work so just posted from the google search. Sorry.